# Why is initializing variables so important?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

Please can someone explain to me, why NOT initializing **first_idx** and **last_idx** causes the code not to run??

When I run it I get this error *"undefined local variable or method last_idx"*. I know that the advice is to always initialize the variables, but I don't understand why. After all first_idx and last_idx will ALWAYS get a value inside the loop because the argument **lette**r is always present in the string (in this particular problem).

I'd really appreciate some (simple) insight. Thank you!

P.S, I also know that the problem is easily solved using #index and #rindex in Ruby, but I'm not allowed to solve it using straightforward methods.

```
def find_for_letter(string, letter)

first_idx = nil
0.upto(string.length - 1) do |idx1|
    if string[idx1] == letter
        first_idx = idx1
        break
    end
end

last_idx = nil
(string.length - 1).downto(0) do |idx2|
    if string[idx2] == letter
        last_idx = idx2
        break
    end
end

if last_idx == first_idx
    return [first_idx]
else
    return [first_idx, last_idx]
end
end



def first_last_indices(word)
    h = {}
    word.chars.each do |char|
        h[char] = find_for_letter(word, char)
    end
    h
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Variables in block

From the [Ruby Programming Language](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do):

> Blocks define a new variable scope: variables created within a block
>   exist only within that block and are undefined outside of the block.
>   Be cautious, however; the local variables in a method are available to
>   any blocks within that method. So if a block assigns a value to a
>   variable that is already defined outside of the block, this does not
>   create a new block-local variable but instead assigns a new value to
>   the already-existing variable.

```
a = 0

2.times do
  a = 1
end

puts a #=> 1

b = 0

2.times do |i;b| # <- b will stay a block-local variable 
  b = 1
end

puts b #=> 0

2.times do |i|
  c = 1
end

puts c #=> undefined local variable or method `c' for main:Object (NameError)
```

## Refactoring your code

#### Iterating with chars and index

Here's a smaller method for your goal.
It keeps a hash with minmax indices for each character.

The default hash value is an empty array.

The method iterates over each character (with index).

If minmax array already contains 2 values :

- it replaces the second one (max) with current index.
- it adds current index to the array otherwise.

```
def first_last_indices(word)
  minmax_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  word.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    minmax = minmax_hash[char]
    if minmax.size == 2
      minmax[1] = index
    else
      minmax << index
    end
  end
  minmax_hash
end

p first_last_indices('hello world')
{"h"=>[0], "e"=>[1], "l"=>[2, 9], "o"=>[4, 7], " "=>[5], "w"=>[6], "r"=>[8], "d"=>[10]}
```

#### With group_by

Here's another possibility. It uses [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html) to get all the indices for each character, and [minmax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) to get just the first and last indices :

```
def first_last_indices(word)
  word.each_char.with_index
      .group_by{ |c, _| c }.map{ |c, vs|
        [c, vs.map(&:last).minmax.uniq]
      }.to_h
end

p first_last_indices('hello world')
{"h"=>[0], "e"=>[1], "l"=>[2, 9], "o"=>[4, 7], " "=>[5], "w"=>[6], "r"=>[8], "d"=>[10]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the simple and straightforward explanation, Eric! It really makes sense now! I'm super happy I learned something new and simple that will prevent future bugs. Also, thank you for the book reference :)                                                                                                                       P.S, Your solution(using a hash) is very interesting, though it's not the most intuitive for me :/

Answer (score 5):

Even if you do not declare `last_idx`, you can still initialise it inside the loop, i.e.:

```
(string.length - 1).downto(0) do |idx2|
    if string[idx2] == letter
        last_idx = idx2 # works absolutely fine
        break
    end
end
```

However notice where you declared the variable. Its a local variable and hence its tied to the block you are in. Now when you try to access that variable outside the block, you get the error:

> undefined local variable or method last_idx

To make the variable available outside the block, you have to declare it outside. That is what you are doing when you declare `last_idx = nil` before the block where its assigned a value.

**UPDATE:**

Though by using instance variables you can avoid declaration, the best practices suggests it should be used in cases where information that these variables have is relevant to all or almost all of the class. On the other hand, if the information is very much limited to this particular method use local variables.

Comment: Thank you @shivam, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4):

This is just the way that local variables work.

If you use instance variables, Ruby will assume that they have been initialised inside the conditional block, but will not for local variables.

```
def find_for_letter(string, letter)

    0.upto(string.length - 1) do |idx1|
        if string[idx1] == letter
            @first_idx = idx1
            break
        end
    end

    (string.length - 1).downto(0) do |idx2|
        if string[idx2] == letter
            @last_idx = idx2
            break
        end
    end

    if @last_idx == @first_idx
        return [@first_idx]
    else
        return [@first_idx, @last_idx]
    end
end
```

This works fine.

Comment: Thank you @DavidAldridge ! Yes, you are right, your code works well :) Thank you for letting me know about instance variables!